# Perform RestTemplate with external TSL

Tags: java, rest, ssl, spring-boot

I'am trying to consume a public REST endpoint that is availablr as in http as SSL `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1` that returns a very simple json.

I have configured my RestTemplate as:

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig {

    @Value("${https.remote.proxy.host}")
    private String PROXY_URI;

    @Value("${https.remote.proxy.port}")
    private int PROXY_PORT;

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {

        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,
        new InetSocketAddress(PROXY_URI, PROXY_PORT));
        requestFactory.setProxy(proxy);

        return new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
    }
}
```

I also when to `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1` in chrome and click in the padlock symbol ⟼ valid ⟼ Details ⟼ Copy to file as jsonplaceholder.cer and with KeyStore explorer I copied the cacerts (JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security).

When I do the next:

```
@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplate;

@RequestMapping(value="test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Post getPost() {
    Post post = restTemplate.getForObject("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1", Post.class);
    return post;
}
```

I got a successful response :

```
{
    "userId": "1",
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
}
```

But when I do the same with the `https` url I got the next error:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1520596009201,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException",
    "message": "I/O error on GET request for \"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1\": sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target",
    "path": "/api/v1/sepa/test/"
}
```

That comes from Java as well:

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
```

What I'm missing? This test is perform because then I have to connect to an vendor API. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same for me with proxy. If you find answer can you add it to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem with your RestTemplate. Vanilla `RestTemplate` works fine for me. Basic debugging procedures - back out things until it starts working. Narrow down the issue.

```
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getRequestFactory().createRequest(new URI("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1"), HttpMethod.GET).execute();
        System.out.println("Got it");
```

Comment: I've tried but does not works. I run the same code outside the proxy and it works even without the certificates in the cacerts.

Comment: Maybe is about the proxy configuration now I'm even worst.